# change position UiButton with Animation Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

i have a button in ViewController and i changed button position when clicked on that . 
**the question it is how to can move button to new position when Clicked with animation ?**

this is view Controller :

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

let X = 50
let Y = 100

let WIDTH = 100
let HEIGHT = 100

 movable_Button.frame = CGRect(x: X, y: Y, width: WIDTH , height: HEIGHT)

    }
```

this is change position method When clicked  :

```
@IBAction func movable_Button_DidTouch(_ sender: Any) {

    movable_Button.frame = CGRect(x: X + 150, y: Y + 150, width: 100, height: 100)


}
```

Comment: just a heads up, camelCase is the standard convention for Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use UIView animate block

```
@IBAction func movableButtonDidTouch(_ sender: Any) {
    // Set initial frame here
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35) {
        // Set final frame here
    }
}
```

Please notice to remove underline (_) in function name, it's not the convention of Swift, use camel case instead.

**Update**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var positions = [CGPoint]()
    let width = 100.0
    let height = 50.0
    var index = 0

    lazy var button: UIButton = {
        let theButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        theButton.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: self.width, height: self.height)
        theButton.backgroundColor = .red
        return theButton
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(self.button)
        for index in 1...4 {
            let point = CGPoint(x: 50 * index, y: 50 * index)
            self.positions.append(point)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func changeButtonPosition(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35) { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.index += 1
            let point = self.positions[self.index % 4]
            self.button.frame = CGRect(origin: point, size: CGSize(width: self.width, height: self.height))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx for your answer . there is a another question i want to ask . how to make 4 diffrent  position for button and change it when clicked on it .

Comment: You can create an array which stores 4 different positions then apply it for the button each time you click on

Comment: I have updated my answer, give you quick example on how to do it, @mehrankmlf. If it's helpful, please accept my answer. Thanks